# JavaScript regex replace the space between two groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I am programmatically modifying a large text file containing some HTML/JS code and need to "mark" locations where there is a space between two selectors, such as between an ID and className, as in $('#btnOne .subElement'). To find these, I need a RegEx. However, I am falling down on the replace bit.

[RegEx101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2wJqEk/1) -- correctly identifies the TWO examples where I need to replace the inside space with a marker (such as $#$#$ or something). (What is wrong with this regex101 demo is that the entire substring is matched, not just the space in the middle - that's all I need to replace)

Here is a code snippet with a replace ready to go, with same problem as above.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 var tmp = $('#orig').text();
 tmp = tmp.replace("<br>", "\n");
 tmp = tmp.replace(/\$\(['"].+ .*\)\./gi,'<span>HOW_TARGET_ONLY_THE_SPACE_CHAR?</span>.');
  $('#output').html(tmp);
});
```

```css
#output{margin-top:10px;background:palegoldenrod;}
span{color:brown;font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orig">
function initSxsChartBtns(){<br>
 var oneBtnIsAlreadyClicked = false;
 $('#databuttons button').each(function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass('btn_DEPRESSED') ) oneBtnIsAlreadyClicked = true;
 });
 if (!oneBtnIsAlreadyClicked){
  $('#txtAdvisory').val('Approximately 25% are registered.');
  $('#btnOne .subElement').addClass('btn_DEPRESSED');
  $('#btnTwo.sameElement').addClass('btn_DEPRESSED');
 }
}
</div>
<button>RegEx Replace</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/(\$\(['"].+) (.*\)\.)/gm, '$1abc$2');
```

Here `$1` and `$2` are used to refer to the capture groups in the RegExp. I've tried to changed your RegExp as little as possible, all I've added is the parentheses to create the capture groups.

`replace` also allows you to pass a function as the second argument, allowing you to control the replacement even more precisely.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Answer is correct, but with small error (corrected, see jsFiddle below). If you had added a demo (jsFiddle or SO Code Snippet - just press Ctrl+M when typing in your answer) - I'd have also upvoted. Appreciate the answer!

Comment: [Here's a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7pamjLp/1/) with skirtle's corrected solution. Thanks skirtle !

Comment: I've corrected the misplaced closing bracket in my RegExp.